# Ajax calendar is not popping up

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCal" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calender.png"/>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2" PopupButtonID="imgCal"  >
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

the same code works on different machine, but mot in mines,
 any code for this is appreciated..
thanks in advance for any suggestion..

Comment: what is the error ? open the javascript console to find it. If no error, then check if the css styles of calendar control exist on your page.

Comment: am not getting any error, it runs but the calender is not popping up:(

Comment: then check the css (get the sdk and see the examples, there is a css part for the calendar, check if this part exist on your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in my machine. Just remove ajax control dll and add latest ajaxcontrol toolkit to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ScriptManager with ToolkitScriptManager.